# Mixing conditional operators with facets in Elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, ruby-on-rails-4, tire, faceted-search

I am trying to match a search query against two fields, as well as filter by facets if selected from dropdowns on the page.

When the user enters keywords it should match if found in two database fields: Title and Description. The dropdowns filter by a status, and a type.

Here is my Tire search configuration:

```
  def self.search(params)
      tire.search(load: true, page: params[:page], per_page: 25) do
        query do
          boolean do
            should { string "title:#{params[:query]}", default_operator: "OR" } if params[:query].present?
            should { string "description:#{params[:query]}", default_operator: "OR" } if params[:query].present?
            must { term :status_id, params[:status_id] } if params[:status_id].present?
            must { term :type_id, params[:type_id] } if params[:type_id].present?
          end
        end
        sort { by :updated_at, "desc" } if params[:query].blank?
        facet "status" do
          terms :status_id
        end
        facet "type" do
          terms :type_id
        end
      end
  end
```

Indexing settings:

```
  settings :analysis => {
      :filter => {
          :my_ngram => {
              "type" => "nGram",
              "max_gram" => 10,
              "min_gram" => 3}
      },
      :analyzer => {
          :my_analyzer => {
              "type" => "custom",
              "tokenizer" => "lowercase",
              "filter" => ["my_ngram"]
          }
      }
  } do
    mapping do
      indexes :title, boost: 10, analyzer: 'my_analyzer'
      indexes :description, boost: 5, analyzer: 'my_analyzer'
      indexes :status_id, :type => 'integer'
      indexes :type_id, :type => 'integer'
    end
  end
```

I originally only had the title and description fields, which was working fine. I am now trying to add the ability to filter by status and type.

What is the proper way to configure this? If status is selected, it should only return records with that status. The same follows for type, and if both are selected.

Any help is appreciated.

It's not that errors occur, but the results no longer filter at all by either keywords or facets:

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/projects/project/_search?load=true&size=25&pretty' -d '{"query":{"bool":{"should":[{"query_string":{"query":"title:test","default_operator":"OR"}},{"query_string":{"query":"description:test","default_operator":"OR"}}],"must":[{"term":{"status_id":{"term":"1"}}},{"term":{"type_id":{"term":"1"}}}]}},"facets":{"status":{"terms":{"field":"status_id","size":10,"all_terms":false}},"type":{"terms":{"field":"type_id","size":10,"all_terms":false}}},"size":25}'

# 2013-08-16 12:08:34:791 [200] (31 msec)
#
# {"took":31,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]},"facets":{"status":{"_type":"terms","missing":0,"total":0,"other":0,"terms":[]},"type":{"_type":"terms","missing":0,"total":0,"other":0,"terms":[]}}}
```

Comment: You should try using filters rather than extra `must` queries if you don't need scoring, It will be much faster. Apart from that, what is the exact problem you are facing? Could you give an error, or list of results that aren't as expected?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have updated my answer with the search result. It now does not filter by keyword or facets. Would you happen to have an example of using filters as opposed to 'must' in my scenario? Perhaps this is the answer I am looking for.

Comment: I don't know if this is the issue, but are you sure you want to be searching for the string "title:test", rather than just "test" in the `title` field? Also note that setting the analyzer like that will set both search and index time analyzers.

Comment: I'm not sure really. I based this setup off the fact that I want to use partial keyword searching. Bear in mind that before adding the two facets, status, and type, the partial word searching was working fine on title or desc. I just need to add the filters. Add an answer with these added / any improved configuration and I will gladly accept :-)

Comment: I don't know tire well enough perhaps to help fully. I would also recommend you read [the docs on facets and filters](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/filter/). I see you are in a sense filtering by "status" in your query. This will affect the status facet only see one term in the result set. i.e. there is no point faceting on a field you have narrowed your search on. Use the top level `"filter"` to filter your results **while still getting a facet count for the query**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you could create the equivalent of this I think you would get the desired results. (Please excuse the lack of quotes on the JSON keys!)

```
{
    query: {
      multi_match: {
        query: "test",
        fields: ["title", "description"]
      }
    },
    filter: {
      and: [
        {
          term: { status_id: 123 }
        },
        {
          term: { type_id: 456 }
        }
      ]
    },
    facets: {
      type: {
        terms: {
          field: "type_id",
          size: 10
        }
      },
      status: {
        terms: {
          field: "status_id",
          size: 10
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Update

I don't know tire but will try to write something!

```
  def self.search(params)
    tire.search(load: true, page: params[:page], per_page: 25) do
      query do
        boolean do
          should { match :title params[:query] } if params[:query].present?
          should { match :description  params[:query] } if params[:query].present?
        end
      end

      sort { by :updated_at, "desc" } if params[:query].blank?

      filter :and, { :term => { :status_id => params[:status_id] } } if params[:status_id].present?
                   { :term => { :type_id => params[:type_id] } } if params[:type_id].present?
    end
  end
```

You will probably have to fix the ruby, but a few things to note. Match queries are the recommended default string search, they are faster than `query_string` ones (though you have slightly less control). Also

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to look into this. I agree this is the type of results I am looking for, however I would like to know how to achieve this with Tire. I have a feeling this will be useful for others as well as many who use ES with Rails also use Tire.

Comment: No worries! Can I ask what problems you are having with the last method (your edit with top-level filters)?

Comment: There's no such thing as a `status` filter... There is `type` filter, but it works on the `type` of document (as in http://domain.com/index/type/id)

Comment: Thanks again. I noticed this right away when I tried testing. I have added my current updates on the question. Filtering by status and type is now working, however I had to break partial word search to get those to work. Any thoughts on how to add them back in so everything will work?

Comment: Sorry, just expand that last bit? Partial word searching; there are 2 ways. stemming words to get the root. Or, fullblown ngramming of the words at index-time to do an autocomplete-like behaviour. (Note, you can do autocomplere with a prefix query but it does a wildcard expansion, which is slow...)

Comment: I really appreciate you sticking with me thus far. I have added one last update, see 'Edit 2'. All I need is to combine the partial word searching to match EITHER 'title' OR 'description'. That's all I need and will be good to go.

Comment: Actually once I filter by a type it now returns every record in that type regardless of keyword :( Removing the partial word piece yet again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35793/discussion-between-ramseykhalaf-and-drew)